# Check exception parameters in assertRaises

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have the following code (using Django):

```
def test_validation(self):
    with assertRaises(ValidationError):
        <do something>

    with assertRaises(ValidationError):
        <do something else>
```

However, there is a difference between the two `ValidationError` exceptions, as I raise them with different `code` values:

```
raise ValidationError("Some message", code='first_code')
```

and

```
raise ValidationError("Another message", code='second_code')
```

Is it possible to check the properties of the raised exceptions, e.g. in my case the `code` property? Adding `code='first_code'` seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html)

*The context manager will store the caught exception object in its exception attribute. This can be useful if the intention is to perform additional checks on the exception raised:*

```
with self.assertRaises(SomeException) as cm:
    do_something()

the_exception = cm.exception
self.assertEqual(the_exception.error_code, 3)
```